# Android: Why am I unable to upload an image to a web server?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I'm using HttpUrlConnection to upload an image to a web server. When I run the app and attempt to upload an image I get a Http response 200 as well as receive the filename and the imageid of the supposed image that has been uploaded, but when i check the server the image was not uploaded. The filename and the id are now part of the list but when I attempt to retrieve the image it returns null.

```
public String uploadFile(String apiPath, String filePath, String type)
{
  String path = "";
  String result = "";

  switch (type)
  {
    case "M":
      path = "Merchant/" + apiPath;
      break;

    case "C":
      path = "Customer/" + apiPath;
      break;
  }

  Log.i(ApiSecurityManager.class.getSimpleName(), m_token);

  String href = "http://tysomapi.fr3dom.net/" + path + "?token=" + m_token;
  Log.i(ApiSecurityManager.class.getSimpleName(), href);
  try
  {
    String myIp = getIp();

    URL url = new URL(href);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "java");

    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary = " + boundary);
    conn.setRequestProperty("X-Forwarded-For", myIp);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    File file = new File(filePath);

    DataOutputStream ds = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    ds.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + LINE_FEED);
    ds.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"" + LINE_FEED);
    ds.writeBytes("ContentType: image/peg" + LINE_FEED);
    ds.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + LINE_FEED);


    FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    int bytesAvailable = fStream.available();

    int maxBufferSize = 1024;
    int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int bytesRead = fStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
      ds.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
      bytesAvailable = fStream.available();
      bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
      bytesRead = fStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    ds.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);
    ds.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + LINE_FEED);

    fStream.close();
    ds.flush();
    ds.close();

    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Response Code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
    if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
        + conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      (conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;

    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
      result = result + output;
    }

    conn.disconnect();
  }

  catch (
    MalformedURLException e
    )

  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  catch (
    IOException e
    )

  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: consider using retrofit

Comment: `"ContentType: image/peg"` ?

Comment: @greenapps is right, you are writting HTTP headers to the `DataOutputStream` directly. I'm not even sure you are uploading an actual image.

Comment: Flush before close is redundant. Your copy loop is all over the place. There are plenty of correct examples here. This isn't one of them. The line terminator in HTTP is not a line feed, it is defined as `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by using PrintWriter and OutputStream instead of DataOutputStream to pass the headers and the image.